# Scope doesn't update in another template (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, html

I have two templates. In this one everything is fine and my variable "score" updates well:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="quizController">

<h1 id="question">{{currentQ.question}}</h1>
<div id="score">Score: {{score}}</div>

<ul class="answers">
    <li ng-repeat="option in currentQ.options">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="answerClick($index)"><p>{{option}}</p></a>
    </li>
</ul>

<button class="prevBtn" ng-click="move(-1)"></button>
<button class="nextBtn" ng-click="move(1)"></button>

</div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller("quizController", function($scope, $http, $location){
$scope.score = 0;
$scope.clicks = 0;

$scope.move = function (direction) {

    if(direction > 0) {
        var position = $scope.allData.indexOf($scope.currentQ);
        $scope.currentQ = $scope.allData[position + direction];
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
};

$http.get("js/json/questions.json").then(function(response){
    $scope.allData = response.data;
    $scope.currentQ = $scope.allData[0];
});

$scope.answerClick = function(index){
    $scope.clicks++;

    if($scope.clicks === 4){
        $location.path('/finish');
    }

    if(index === $scope.currentQ.answer){
        $scope.score++;
        $scope.move(+1);
    }
    else{
        $scope.move(+1);
    }
};

});
```

But in this template score counter doesn't work:

HTML:

```
<div id="finish-score">Your Score: {{score}}</div>
<a class="btn btn-danger tryagainBtn" href="#/game"><p>Try again</p></a>
```

Problem is in scopes but I don't know exactly how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is that you are using the same controller for all states: root, game and finish. Each time you enter a new state, the controller would be reinitialized for the new view.

The first line of your code is `$scope.score = 0;`, that's why `score` is always 0 when entering `finish` state. A proper way of fixing this bug is leveraging Angular service, which is singleton, to store the score data.

```
app.controller("quizController", function($scope, $http, $location, resultService){
    $scope.score = resultService.score;
    $scope.clicks = 0;

    $scope.move = function (direction) {

        if(direction > 0) {
            var position = $scope.allData.indexOf($scope.currentQ);
            $scope.currentQ = $scope.allData[position + direction];
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    };

    $http.get("questions.json").then(function(response){
        $scope.allData = response.data;
        $scope.currentQ = $scope.allData[0];
    });

    $scope.answerClick = function(index){
        $scope.clicks++;

        if($scope.clicks === 4){
            resultService.score = $scope.score;
            $location.path('/finish');
        }

        if(index === $scope.currentQ.answer){
            $scope.score++;
            $scope.move(+1);
        }
        else{
            $scope.move(+1);
        }
    };

});
app.service("resultService", function () {
  var resultService = { 
    score:0
  };
  return resultService;
});
```

Personally I suggest use different controller for different states/views, and keep using service for data storage/sharing. You can separate functionalities to `homeController`, `quizController`, `resultController`

HomeController

```
app.controller("homeController", function($scope,){
    // currently we can do nothing in homeController
}
```

QuizController

```
app.controller("quizController", function($scope, $http, $location, resultService){
    // Same as legacy code
    $scope.score = resultService.score;
    ....
}
```

ResultController

```
app.controller("resultController", function($scope, $http, $location, resultService){
        $scope.score = resultService.score;
        $scope.tryAgain = function () {
          resultService.score = 0;
          $location.path('/game');
        }
}
```

Besides, change your route to

```
when('/', {
  templateUrl: '',
  controller: 'homeController' 
})
when('/game', {
  templateUrl: '',
  controller: 'quizController' 
}).
when('/finish', {
  templateUrl: '',
  controller: 'resultController'
}
```

Thus quizController will be loaded only when users visit '/#/game'.

Comment: Now score counter is working but when it goes to the finish and the score, for example, eqauls 1 the user click on "Try again" and score is now counting from 1, not from 0. Can you show how to handle this app with different controllers please so I will understand the idea? Thanks for the reply

Comment: It would be easy if you only want to reset the score when users click `try again`. Add a function `$scope.tryAgain = function () { resultService.score = 0; $location.path('/game'); }` and change your view to `<a class="btn btn-danger tryagainBtn" ng-click="tryAgain()"><p>Try again</p></a>`

Comment: @ovesyan check my update for separating controllers.

Comment: I've already made it with separate controllers and it looks like your variant, and everything works fine now. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

$scope in angular works the same as variable scope in other programming languages.

Your variable $scope.scores is only available within the scope of the controller, so only within the div tag that declares it with the ng-controller directive.

If you want to make it available outside of the scope, you can declare the angular equivalent of global variables with $rootscope.

Comment: Better variant to do it with factories, how do you think? Can you show your solution with $rootScope?

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work to me. Do I have to change all functions which are using $scope to $rootScope or I can change only score variable. Cause when I change only "score" it doesn't update

Comment: what controller your second HTML view belongs to ?

Comment: @Rebornix the same as the first one

Comment: If it's in the same controller, which means, they are in the same scope, it should work. Would you pls create a plnkr/jsfiddler app for better debugging?

Comment: @Rebornix It's not working properly in Plnkr, but I pasted all the code so you can work with it in your IDE. Here is the plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/jwmZJrLgy5AsPuK2PPja